# Tolerance bound for a normalized variable

Tags: normal-distribution, tolerance-interval

Based on a sample $(x_i) \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, how can you get an exact or a well-approximated upper tolerance bound (i.e. an upper confidence bound of a quantile of the distribution) of $\dfrac{x_i}{\sigma}$ ? Here, we assume both parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown.

Comment: Presumably, both parameters are unknown.

Comment: @whuber Yes they are.

Comment: You can calculate likelihood-confidence intervals of this quantity by using that $x_i/\sigma \sim N(\mu,1)$. Using this, you have that the $p$th quantile of $x_i/\sigma$ is $q=\mu+\Phi^{-1}(p)$, then you can reparameterise the likelihood of $(\mu,\sigma)$ in terms of $(q,\sigma)$ and to obtain the profile likelihood of $q$ and the corresponding approximate confidence interval by the usual methods. There must be an exact approach but I do not know it.

Comment: Thanks @Procrastinator. As you can see I answer my own question. Starting a bounty when you have a cold is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

Damn! After starting the bounty I realized the answer is easy: The quantile has form $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+z_p$, and there are some known methods to get a confidence interval about the "effect size" $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$ (or by inverting the bounds of a confidence interval about the coefficient of variation; such a confidence interval is available in the [R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MBESS/index.html) `MBESS`).

Answer (score 5):

In *Environmental Statistics with S-Plus* (CRC Press, 2001), Steven Millard and Nagaraj Neerchal state that a

> ***$\beta$-content*** tolerance interval with ***confidence level*** $(1-\alpha)100$% is constructed so that it contains *at least* $\beta 100$% of the population (*i.e.*, the coverage is at least $\beta 100$%) with probability $(1-\alpha)100$%.

Citing several sources (Wald & Wolfowitz 1946, Guttman 1970, Gibbons 1994), they give an *approximate* two-sided tolerance interval for $n$ observations in the usual form of (sample mean) + $K$ (sample standard deviation) where

$$K = r \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{\chi^2_{n-1, \alpha}}}.$$

Here, $\chi^2_{n-1,\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$ quantile of a chi-square distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom and $r$ solves the equation

$$\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + r) - \Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - r) -\beta$$

(with $\Phi$ the standard Normal CDF).

> Wald and Wolfowitz (1946) show that this approximation is quite good, even for values of $n$ as small as $2$, provided both $\beta$ and $1-\alpha$ are greater than $0.95$.  Furthermore, Ellison (1964) shows that for this approximation, the error in the confidence level is on the order of $1/n$.

Millard & Neerchal also discuss the simpler case of a *one-sided tolerance interval*, where $K$ is given by

$$K = \frac{t_{n-1, z_\beta \sqrt{n}, 1-\alpha}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

The notation $t_{\nu, \delta, p}$ refers to the $p^\text{th}$ quantile of the non-central Student t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\delta$, and $z_p$ refers to the $p^\text{th}$ quantile of the standard Normal distribution, $z_p = \Phi^{-1}(p)$.  This directly answers the present question.

---

#### Software

I provide an Excel (VBA) macro for these (Normal-theory) intervals in a spreadsheet at http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/software/intervals.xls.  Although I have not tried it, the `R` package [tolerance](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tolerance/index.html) appears to offer a broad suite of tolerance intervals (these formulas need to be modified to apply to regression residuals, for instance).

The non-central Student t distribution is available via the `ncp` argument through the `qt` function (and its relatives) found in the base `R` installation.

---

#### References

Wald, A., and J. Wolfowitz. (1946). *Tolerance Limits for a Normal Distribution.*  Annals of Mathematical Statistics **17**, 208-215.

Guttman, I. (1970) *Statistical Tolerance Regions: Classical and Bayesian.*  Hafner Publishing Co., Darien, CT.

(I omit the Gibbons reference because it has typographical errors and adds nothing fundamentally different.)

Comment: Thanks for providing these informations. But I don't see how you apply the classical theory for a Gaussian sample to the case of my question. Do you claim you divide the classical tolerance bound for $(x_i)$ by $\hat\sigma$ ?

Comment: I missed that point. Your answer is indeed correct: you only need to add a constant to a confidence limit for the coefficient of variation $\mu/\sigma$. (+1 to your answer for that.) However, I have long wanted to have an exposition of the basic theory of tolerance intervals somewhere on this site, so if you don't mind, I would like to keep my answer open: in that way this thread will provide a reference for several kinds of tolerance intervals.

Comment: Yes, your post contains useful information.