# Estimate Percentile of normal distribution from a sample

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

I need to estimate 90th percentile of a normal distribution. Assuming that I have a small sample(<30) of the population of this distribution how can I estimate the 90th percentile? what assumptions can I make regarding the distribution of the sample. I think CLT is not applicable here because I dont want any CI for the mean. Note that the standard deviation of the population is unknown.

Comment: Another term for estimates of percentiles--especially when it is desired to provide a confidence limit for the estimate--is [*tolerance limit*.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44743/tolerance-bound-for-a-normalized-variable/47326#47326).  One answer in the duplicate answers your question and another answer explains how to obtain tolerance limits for Normal distributions.