How to determine the percentile with a certain confidence?
The so called characteristic strength of a material should be the lower 5 % percentile of the population, according to the Eurocode when verifying the load bearing capacity of construction works. The strength of the material in a population is assumed to be normal distributed. For large samples it can be assumed to be the mean value of the sample minus 1.645 times the standard error of the sample.
However, for small samples it should be the lower 5 % percentile determined as the mean value minus a certain factor times the standard error. This factor depends on the number of samples and the level of confidence should be equal to 75 %. This factor is getting closer to 1.645 as the number of samples increase. The t-distribution is used, I assume, plus some factor to account for the 75 % confidence. The t-factor is e.g. 2.92 for the lower 5 % point value for a sample of n=3 and thus 2 degrees of freedom. However, according to a table used for small samples the factor is 3.19 for n=3. The true standard error is assumed to be unknown.
This factor is, in a case with known standard error, 1.645 + 0.67/(n^0.5), where 0,67 is the Z-value for the upper 25 % percentile. So for a sample of 3 it would be 1.645 + 0.387 = 2.031.
As you have already understod I am not a statistician, and my examples above are probably not so easy to understand. Anyway, my question is: how are the factors for samples with unknown true standard error calculated?

This is known as a lower tolerance limit.  See, for instance, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26702 for a general discussion and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44743/ for an explicit answer.
